# Getting the multi-level category (main category, category, sub-category) of scrapped items

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape data from an online shop in the following manner: group(Food) > category(Rice/Pasta) > subcategory(Oatmeal) products. Currently I am able to scrape group(Food) > products. As shown in the images below, I want to be able to get all products from all groups (Food, Electric products, Household items, etc) but with its corresponding Group, Category, and Sub-Category.

[image]
[image]

**My current data:**
[image]

**My expected data:**
[image]

In addition to getting all levels of categories, I wanted to get the product serial code too which is available when you click the product itself as shown in the image below.
[image]

My current code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
from datetime import datetime

categories = {
    "6011": {"pages": 46, "name": "Цахилгаан бараа"},
    "24175": {"pages": 63, "name": "Food"},
    "24273": {"pages": 32, "name": "Гэр ахуй"},
    "21297": {"pages": 48, "name": "Гоо сайхан"},
    "19653": {"pages": 4, "name": "Гутал, хувцас"},
    "19451": {"pages": 3, "name": "Авто бараа"},
    "19518": {"pages": 16, "name": "Барилгын материал"},
    "19853": {"pages": 3, "name": "Аялал, Спорт бараа"},
    "19487": {"pages": 40, "name": "Ном"},
    "19767": {"pages": 5, "name": "Бичиг хэрэг"},
    "19469": {"pages": 3, "name": "Эрүүл мэнд"},
    "19545": {"pages": 12, "name": "Хүүхдийн бараа"},
}

dt_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = dt_today + ' Nomin'


class Nomin(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nomin'
    custom_settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
            f'{filename}.csv': {
                'format': 'csv',
                'overwrite': True}}
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for cat, val in categories.items():
            for page in range(1, val["pages"]):
                url = f'https://eshop.nomin.mn/graphql?query=query+category%28%24pageSize%3AInt%21%24currentPage%3AInt%21%24filters%3AProductAttributeFilterInput%21%24sort%3AProductAttributeSortInput%29%7Bproducts%28pageSize%3A%24pageSize+currentPage%3A%24currentPage+filter%3A%24filters+sort%3A%24sort%29%7Bitems%7Bid+name+sku+brand+salable_qty+brand_name+c21_available+c21_business_type+c21_reference+c21_street+c21_area+c21_bed_room+mp_daily_deal%7Bcreated_at+date_from+date_to+deal_id+deal_price+remaining_time+deal_qty+discount_label+is_featured+product_id+product_name+product_sku+sale_qty+status+store_ids+updated_at+__typename%7Dnew_to_date+short_description%7Bhtml+__typename%7DproductAttributes%7Bname+value+__typename%7Dprice%7BregularPrice%7Bamount%7Bcurrency+value+__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dspecial_price+special_to_date+thumbnail%7Bfile_small+url+__typename%7Durl_key+url_suffix+mp_label_data%7Benabled+name+priority+label_template+label_image+to_date+__typename%7D...on+ConfigurableProduct%7Bvariants%7Bproduct%7Bsku+special_price+price%7BregularPrice%7Bamount%7Bcurrency+value+__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dpage_info%7Btotal_pages+__typename%7Dtotal_count+__typename%7D%7D&operationName=category&variables=%7B%22currentPage%22%3A{page}%2C%22id%22%3A{cat}%2C%22filters%22%3A%7B%22category_id%22%3A%7B%22in%22%3A%22{cat}%22%7D%7D%2C%22pageSize%22%3A50%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22news_from_date%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%7D'
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    url,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    cb_kwargs={"category": val["name"]}
                )

    def parse(self, response, category=None):
        data = response.json()
        if data and data['data'] and data['data']['products'] and data['data']['products']['items']:
            for item in data['data']["products"]["items"]:
                yield {
                    "Product Name": item["name"],
                    "Category": category,
                    "price": item["price"]["regularPrice"]["amount"]["value"],
                    "special_price": item["special_price"],
                    "Product Description": item["short_description"]["html"]
                }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(Nomin)
    process.start()
```

All and any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: The answer to this question is likely very similar to my previous answer in that you need to find the subcategory ids and do the same type of substitution in the api url...  I did a breif search but wasn't able to find where to get them, but that is likely because I don't understand the language.

Comment: @Alexander could you share what results showed for your brief search? I inspected network activity and checked the header for the data api but could not identify a pattern for the subcategory ids. The category ids seem to be different for category and sub categories. For example, [Food/Grocery](https://eshop.nomin.mn/n-foods.html) is 24175, but [pickled products](https://eshop.nomin.mn/n-foods/zagas-shiltjej-nogoo.html) is 28140, and [sweet spreads](https://eshop.nomin.mn/n-foods/kompot-chanamal.html) is 28146.  I couldn't find any subcategory id in the headers.

Comment: @Alexander for example how would you scrape a website that does not seem to have a data api in their network activity search? Or is there another method to see? For example, [category1: women's clothing](https://shoppy.mn/t/women) and [category2: mens clothing](https://shoppy.mn/t/men) for this [website](https://shoppy.mn/). Would you just create a list or dictionary of urls and use xpaths?

Comment: That is what I mean, when I say subcategory ids.  I was hoping that there was an api endpoint that could return all of the different categories and subcategories along with their ID's but I wasn't able to discover one.  But I don't really know what I am looking for at the same time since I don't know what is an isn't a category in the language.

Comment: If the target site was rendered from javascript and didn't have an api endpoint to query, then the next option would be to use playwright or selenium to extract the information.